# Html.RouteLink 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can anyone help with this problem, I have the following routelink:

```
 @Html.RouteLink(@item.strCountry, "WeatherCity", new {id=Regex.Replace(@item.strCountry, " ","-") })
```

In my RouteConfig I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "WeatherCity",
            url: "Cities-In/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Weather", action = "Cities", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

In my controller I have:

```
 public PartialViewResult Cities(string id)
```

also tried

```
public ActionResult Cities(string id)
```

But no matter what I do I get a 404 error.

I have tried following numerous examples the last one been:

http://davecowart.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/named-routes-in-asp-net-mvc-3/

Am I missing something simple here as I cannot get this to work, i'm using MVC4.

Any help would be appreciated

George

Comment: For start, use [Route Debugger](http://nuget.org/packages/routedebugger)

Comment: Hi get the following, False

Cities-In/{id}

controller = Weather, action = Cities, id = UrlParameter.Optional

(empty)

(empty) question is why when reading other examples it works, but mine does not

Comment: But have you used Route Debugger? It's handy to know some tools to work with rather than just an answer to a very specific question. I could try guessing the answer to your question by one of the first best shots would be using Route Debugger and see how the route parsing goes and where it fails.

Comment: Hi I'm using Route Debugger, what I posted above is what its displaying

Comment: What does your link look like? In the HTML itself.

Comment: HTML link example <a href="/Cities-In/Afghanistan">Afghanistan</a>

Comment: Route-Debugger shows controller - Cities-In. action United-Kingdom should be controller weather action cities I can see why its throwing a 404, but all examples I have seen like post I submitted should work.

Comment: The id parameter is "optional" so when getting something like /Cities-In/Afghanistan it does not use Afghanistan as the optional ID but as the Action and you get the 404 error (route is not mapping). Try setting the id Url parameter as mandatory and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found your issue (reference for readers: the "comments" conversation under the question).

You should put your `routes.MapRoute()` thing *before* the default route. Else, the default route is matched and run (and MVC stops looking further to any subsequent route rules). MVC matches your URL against the default route, but then it doesn't find a corresponding action (`Cities`) in the *DefaultController*.

Comment: Seems this is a bigger problem than I thought, removed all routes except default and it now trying to load weather/home as home page, even though that page has been excluded from project. Looks like its going to take a while to track this problem down. Thanks everyone for their help

Comment: Don't just drop your default route - put it last. So MVC will first try to match against specific routes and only fall back to the default if none succeeds.

Comment: Seems the problem was VS, keeped crashing and restarting then finally crashed for good and could not re-start it. Once repaired, routes work ok. :-( thanks for everyones help, must have been a corrupt file causing the problems

Comment: Can't believe it's related to Visual Studio. It's just an editor. The real things happen in IIS and in the MVC engine. You probably got it right after playing a while with the routes.

Comment: @CareerChange, have I answered your question?

Comment: Hi Ofer, sorry forgot to get back, yes, if I have 2 routes but both have different controllers and actions, it throws a 404, I need to reference the route via named route to fix the problem